# Какая логика приложение на Android, психологического теста?

Tags: java, android

Вопрос очень абстрактный, я это понимаю и ответ естественно жду примерно такой же.

Какая логика приложение на Android, психологического теста?
Понятно, что нужно использовать конструкцию `if else`, но что дальше делать, не совсем понятно.

Например есть три вопроса, в каждом вопросе по два выбора ответа и в конце выводиться результат.

Например пользователь нажал в первом вопросе на кнопку 1, я пишу `if (a==1)` то `{}`, и как лучше дальше сделать перенаправить на другое активити с помощью intent или есть более правильный способ?

Comment: В книгах П.Дейтела "Андроид для разработчиков" и Б.Харди "Андроид. Программирование для проффесионалов" есть полные и очень подробные [примеры разработки приложения-викторины](https://books.google.ru/books?id=8E_ADAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1&hl=ru&pg=PA165#v=onepage&q&f=false)
 (фактически теста)  - несколько вопросов, выбор вариантов, подведение итогов и тд.

Comment: Уверен, что прочитав  соответствующие главы в книгах, вы в полной мере решите все проблемы логики приложений для тестов, а прочитав в них всё, узнаете множество крайне полезной информации до такой степени, что сможете сами отвечать на вопросы, а не задавать их.

Comment: pavlofff спасибо обязательно прочитаю

Answer (score 2):

В случае если у Вас будет много вопросов, то городить кучу активностей/фрагментов совсем не обязательно, вы "сожрете" кучу ресурсов телефона при таком подходе. По сути (как я понял из Вашего условия) у вас есть вопрос и варианты ответов на него. Сделайте одну активность в которой будет TextView (сам вопрос) ,несколько RadioButton  и Button для перехода на следующий вопрос. При нажатии на кнопку вы будете записывать выбранный ответ в свою модель данных и затем переопределять значения TextView и RadioButton.

Comment: Я Вас понял спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
switch (answer) {
  case someAnswer1: 
     //todo 
     Intent otherActivity = new Intent (OtherActivity.this);
     break;
  case someAnswer2:
     //todo
     Intent anotherActivity = new Intent (AnotherActivity.this);
     break;
  case .....
.....
break;
```

Псевдокод, но  в целом это будет выглядеть так. Городить кучу `if` не обязательно.

Comment: Спасибо! Примерно так и собирался сделать